# Regex to match any language characters with allowing whitespaces

Tags: java, regex

I want to verify user input on the fields where user can enter his name, surname, city, other geo data.

I want this regex to be internationalized so if user for example has characters in his surname from spanish, english, russian language he can pass on this regex.

And if the geo data has for example city or street with compound name and whitespaces like: `Foo Bar` street then it's also pass this test.

I was trying this regex with no success: `"\\p{L}+\\s*"`

I'm using it in such case:

```
public static boolean isFilled(String... values) {

    if (checkNull(values)) {
        return false;
    }

    for (String value : values) {

        if (!value.matches(filledRegex)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A name shouldn't start or end with a space. You should use this regex with anchors:

```
"^\\p{L}[\\p{L}\\s]*\\p{L}$"
```